# Why does creating an unrelated index make my query faster?

Tags: sql, postgresql, optimization, indexing, sql-execution-plan

I have a table:

```
debts (
    name       text,
    inv_no     integer,
    inv_type   text,
    status     text,
);
```

I have a following select:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM debts WHERE name = '...' AND inv_no = 100 AND inv_type = '...';
```

To optimize something else, I added:

```
CREATE INDEX ON debt (status);
```

Nowhere in SELECT do I refer to the status, yet running...

```
EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(*)... (as above)
```

...before and after creating index gives me cost 16.65..16.66 changing into 1.25..1.26. Why?

Full `explain (analyze, verbose)` before/after:

Before:

```
QUERY PLAN
----------
 Aggregate  (cost=16.65..16.66 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.126..0.128 rows=1 loops=1)
   Output: count(*)
   ->  Seq Scan on ab123456.debts  (cost=0.00..16.65 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.106..0.106 rows=0 loops=1)
         Output: name, inv_no, inv_type, status
         Filter: ((debts.name = '...'::text) AND (debts.inv_type = '...'::text) AND (debts.inv_no = 100))
 Total runtime: 0.387 ms
```

After:

```
QUERY PLAN
----------
 Aggregate  (cost=1.25..1.26 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.031..0.033 rows=1 loops=1)
   Output: count(*)
   ->  Seq Scan on ab123456.debts  (cost=0.00..1.25 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.024..0.024 rows=0 loops=1)
         Output: name, inv_no, inv_type, status
         Filter: ((debts.name = '...'::text) AND (debts.inv_type = '...'::text) AND (debts.inv_no = 100))
 Total runtime: 0.118 ms
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include the full plans that you got.

Comment: I don't know why, and I don't think you've given us enough information to figure out why, but you probably could get some insight by running an explain plan to see if/how the query is using the new index.

Comment: dlugi == debt ?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have edited the question, adding full "explain (analyze, verbose)"-generated plans and correcting translation mistakes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some utility statements (including `CREATE INDEX`!) update table statistics while being at it. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/planner-stats.html)

> For efficiency reasons, `reltuples` and `relpages` are not updated
>   on-the-fly, and so they usually contain somewhat out-of-date values.
>   They are updated by `VACUUM`, `ANALYZE`, and a few DDL commands such as **`CREATE INDEX`**.

Bold emphasis mine. So even if your index seems completely unrelated, the updated table statistics can have an impact - especially on `count()` which primarily depends on the two statistics mentioned.

Related:

- [PostgreSQL partial index unused when created on a table with existing data](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/99323/postgresql-partial-index-unused-when-created-on-a-table-with-existing-data/99324#99324)